# Can I change the default sphere display of native Geometry Nodes point clouds?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to change the default point shape of the instances from a sphere to something else?
without instancing any object on the points.
THank you!

Comment: Short answer: unfortunately no. (At least not as long as you don't edit the source code and compile Blender yourself).

Comment: this is sad, i hope they add it in the near future, thank yououou

Comment: Hello, I changed the title so that it's a little bit more clear what your question is about, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

> Just to be able to mark this question as "solved" (for now), a short answer to this:

It is unfortunately not possible to change the shape of the points without changing the source code.

However, you can instantiate another simple shape at the points, for example a small cube instead of the diamond shape. Technically, nothing else happens with the default display: simple shapes are instantiated at the points ...only that this happens auomatically.

However, if your question is more about increasing performance in the viewport because you want to instantiate more complex objects, for example, you would still have the following option:

[image]

Here I use a switch that is controlled by the input node `Is Viewport`.

In the viewport, the points are displayed, but when you render the whole thing, the objects you want are instantiated instead.

...maybe this will help you anyway.